# iFrames not loading at all on iOS

Tags: ios, css, html, iframe

I have a [website](http://hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile/) with an [iFrame](http://hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile#page5) on it that loads fine when I am on a desktop browser, but not on iOS (I haven't tried any other mobile OS's). The code I used for the iFrame is

```
<div data-role="content">
<iframe src="http://hungrcraft.co.nf/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0" seamless>
</iframe>
</div>
```

along with

```
body, html
{
margin: 0; padding: 0;  overflow: hidden;
}
#content
{
position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0; 
}
```

in a css/text style tag.

As I said earlier, this loads on desktop web browsers, and in IE11 emulations, but not on iOS (tested 3.1.3-7.0.4). Is there something I did wrong? Is this a bug with iFrames? HTML? HTML5? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Looks like you have a redirect loop. On hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile#page5 you have an iframe for hungrcraft.co.nf. However, it appears that hungrcraft.co.nf detects if you are on a mobile device which redirects the iframe to http://hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhungrcraft.co.nf%2F displaying your mobile page in the iframe that was supposed to show your homepage.

Original Post:
What device are you using? That site you linked pulls up fine in my iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: The website I used in the previous post doesn't load. (hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile#page5)

Comment: Sorry, i reread your post and noticed you linked a site. http://hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile/ appears to load the iFrame just fine in my iPhone 5. What device are you using?

Comment: That's really weird. It doesn't load at all for me, just flashes white then goes back to the nav screen. I have tested it on a 4S (jailbroken, iOS 7.0.4), 3GS (jailbroken, iOS 6.1.3), 2G (4.1, jailbroken), 2G (4.2.1, unjailbroken), 2G (3.1.3, jailbroken), and 3G (5.1.1, unjailbroken). They all flash white and then back to nav.

Comment: What page are you supposed to see? I'm seeing a page that has 4 links to Home, Videos, Old Page and Full Site with black bars on top and bottom. That's also what I see on the desktop though, so I assumed it was correct.

Comment: I think i see what's going on, do you have any mobile detection / redirection going on in your homepage? It looks like hungrcraft.co.nf/ will redirect to hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile on iOS devices. So if you expect hungrcraft.co.nf/mobile#page5 to redirect to the root, it might be just redirecting right back. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how I'm to show the home page, however. I don't want to copy and paste the full site, as I am constantly making changes. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Try embedding the iFrame, it's a push but it may work.

```
<embed src="http://hungrcraft.co.nf/"</embed>
```

P.S I have tried on my iTouch 5, it's loading fine for me.